# Coloco um jquery e o site entra direto id

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho esse script com css e jQuery de abas de cores diferentes, quando incluo a linha:

Para deixar aberta a primeira aba.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.abas:first').trigger('click').focus();
    });
```

O site inicia na class `.abas`, e não do começo, como podem ver aqui

https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/9/

Como faria pro site começar do começo?

Comment: Não consegui entender o que está acontecendo de errado. Para mim quando eu executo o jsfiddle a Aba 1 vem selecionada.

Comment: sim mais perceba q inicia da aba selecionada o site e não do topo

Comment: "inicia da aba selecionada" o que quer dizer isso? mas se o "site" é tão pequeno em altura que nem exige barra de rolagem, como iniciaria de outro lugar a não ser todo o conteúdo dele sendo exibido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o evento focus.
Ele faz com que a tela fique encima do item em que esta chamado pelo $...
Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var position = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.abas:first').trigger('click').focus();
    $(window).scrollTop(position);
});
```

Comment: assim não fica a primeira aba selecionada

Comment: Realmente não funcionou, foi mal pega caquinha... Editei o post, teste agora. Dessa vez eu testei no jsfiddle que vc passou e o codigo atual funcionou lá

Comment: agora sim hehhehe

Answer (score 1):

Eles está pulando direto porque você define o foco na aba com o `focus()`

```
$('.abas:first').trigger('click').focus();
$('.abas:first').trigger('click'); // Dessa forma não ficaria selecionado de largada
```

O evento focus é enviado para um elemento quando ele ganha foco. Elementos com foco geralmente são destacados de alguma forma pelo navegador, por exemplo, com uma linha pontilhada que envolve o elemento. O foco é usado para determinar qual elemento é o primeiro a receber eventos relacionados ao teclado, como um campo de email em uma tela de login por exemplo.

Um método muito usado para isso que está tentando, é a adição de uma classe para definir o elemento ativo, exemplo:

```js
$('.abas').on('click', function(){
   $('.abas').removeClass('active'); // linha adicionada
   $(this).addClass('active');  // linha adicionada
   aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');

   this.aba1 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">dsad</div>'
   }

   this.aba2 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">asdsad</div>'
   }

   this.aba3 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">zxczx czxc zx</div>'
   }

   this.aba4 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas">dffxg f</div>'
   }

   this.aba5 = {
      conteudo: '<div class="conteudo_abas"> sdfdsf </div>'
   }

  return $('#texto').html(this['aba' + aba_index]['conteudo']);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.abas:first').trigger('click').addClass('active'); // linha atualizada focus - addClass
   
});
```

```css
.conteudo_abas{
  border:1px solid #000;  
}
.abas{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   padding: 0 15px;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
   float: left;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
}

.abas:hover,
.abas:focus, .abas.active{
   color: #fff;
}

.abas:nth-child(1){
   border-bottom-color: orange;
}
   .abas:nth-child(1):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(1).active{
      background: orange;
   }

.abas:nth-child(2){
   border-bottom-color: red;
}
   .abas:nth-child(2):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(2).active {
      background: red;
   }

.abas:nth-child(3){
   border-bottom-color: purple;
}
   .abas:nth-child(3):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(3).active{
      background: purple;
   }

.abas:nth-child(4){
   border-bottom-color: blue;
}
   .abas:nth-child(4):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(4).active{
      background: blue;
   }

.abas:nth-child(5){
   border-bottom-color: green;
}
   .abas:nth-child(5):hover,
   .abas:nth-child(5).active{
      background: green;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-top:1000px;">
</div>
<div class="abas abas1" tabindex="1">
   Aba 1
</div>
<div class="abas abas2" tabindex="2">
   Aba 2
</div>
<div class="abas abas3" tabindex="3">
   Aba 3
</div>
<div class="abas abas4" tabindex="4">
   Aba 4
</div>
<div class="abas abas5" tabindex="5">
   Aba 5
</div>
<br clear="all" /><br />
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Comment: quando eu tiro o focus() a primeira aba não vem selecionada, como faria para deixar selecionada e não pular?

Comment: Editei a resposta Wagner, editei no fiddle tbm... https://jsfiddle.net/x9rtxsv5/10/

Comment: qual linhas vc trocou ali? pode me dizer?

Comment: Comentei na resposta, foram 3 linhas no jQuery, e no CSS alterei os elementos com :focus para .active, na verdade todas linhas que tiverem um .active foram alteradas, mas só adicionadas a classe ou colocada no lugar do focus